# @DataJpaTest and @WebMvcTest stopped working after upgrade to 2.2.0

Tags: spring-boot

After upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.8 to 2.2.0 tests that are not loading full application context started failing.

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    ....
    }
```

This produces the following error

```
20:44:35.866 [main] [ERROR] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method rabbitTemplate in com.example.boot.message.amqp.AmqpConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory' in your configuration.
```

I'm getting the same error on @WebMvcTest but both worked perfectly fine before.

Injection fails on @RestController class which I don't think should be scanned and loaded for the @DataJpaTest.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem was @ComponentScan annotation on the application class, replacing @ComponentScan with @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example") resolved the issue.